# SAS/SQL Using Teradata.UPDATE syntax

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a temporary table "temp" where I have some data which I wish to map with another table ip_geo_data_location. I wish to generate location_id in temp from the other table along with the conditions mentioned as follows:
Error is follows: "ERROR: Teradata execute: Alias name defined should be used instead of table name temp."

```
update temp
from temp a, ip_geo_data_location b
set a.location_id=b.location_id
where a.ablock=b.ip_start_1
and a.bblock=b.ip_start_2
and a.ip_integer between b.ip_start and b.ip_end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes find update syntax slightly confusing and so writing the update as a sub-query can help.

```
update temp
from
(
  select
  a.location_id
  ,a.ablock
  ,a.bblock
  ,a.ip_integer
  from temp as a

  inner join ip_geo_data_location as b
  on b.ip_start_1 = a.ablock
  and b.ip_start_2 = a.bblock
  and a.ip_integer between b.ip_start and b.ip_end
)sub
set location_id = sub.location_id
where temp.ablock = sub.ablock
and temp.bblock = sub.bblock
and temp.ip_integer = sub.ip_integer
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
FROM temp a, ip_geo_data_location b
SET a.location_id = b.location_id
WHERE a.ablock = b.ip_start_1
AND a.bblock = b.ip_start_2
AND a.ip_integer BETWEEN b.ip_start AND b.ip_end;
```

Comment: the problem is that temp is already a table which I wish to update. Changing the syntax to update "a" gives the message that object "a" does not exist